# What result do sed 's;//;/;g' and egrep "\-example (|\:)$variablename:" give?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm writing some automation for getting perticular path, I got the code, but I'm unable to understand what exactly the below commands does?

```
sed 's;//;/;g'
egrep "\-example (|\:)$variablename:"
```

Answer (score 2):

In sed, it is common to use `/` as a delimiter for the `s` command, but any character will do and it is common to choose a character that does not appear in either the pattern or the replacement.  In this case, `;` was chosen as the delimiter.  This command is simply replacing occurrences of `//` with `/`.  It is equivalent to the (IMO) more readable :`s@//@/@g`

The egrep is a syntax error which perhaps should have been written: `egrep "-example (:)?$variablename:"`, which will match text with or without the `:`.  (That is, if `variablename=foo`, then this will match either `-example foo:` or `-example :foo:`.  That may not be what is intended, but it's hard to say since the given example is not valid syntax.  It appears to want to provide alternatives between a `:` or something else, but the alternative is missing.)